# Detecting syntax error in css file and ruby on rails. invalid css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am encountering a problem when trying to push my code up to heroku. I have run:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

and got this error:

```
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "  color: #f19f4d;5": expected "{", was ";"
(sass):916
```

I understand there is syntax error somewhere in my css yet i have gone through all my files and can not find this line. Can someone please tell me if there is way to locate this line or where it could possibly be. Thank you so much!

Comment: Is `color: #f19f4d;5` a valid color? That `;5` looks suspicious.

Comment: I dont think that is a valid color and the actual css is coming from another developer. The problem is i can not find that line to fix it.

Comment: does the (sass):916 part mean it is somewhere on line 916. Thank you in advance

Comment: Not sure. Try grepping (searches content of files) it in the command prompt. You can google the details on how to do that.

Comment: will try that now thank you

Comment: did you do full text search for `f19f4d` ?

Comment: no i have not done that is there a good wy to do that besides grep

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap, it depends on jQuery so you'll need to make sure to include it in your application stylesheet so for example in `app/assets/stylesheets` toward the top of the file and before any bootstrap includes or imports you'll need

```
//*= require jquery-ui
```

If that's not the problem, thaen precompilation is failing due to some kind of syntax error.  First try to any occurrence of `f19f4d` in your code by doing a full text search of your code.  If you have a *nix based system you can just try either of these from the terminal,

if you are using git version control

```
git grep f19f4d
```

Or just

```
grep f19f4d
```

If that doesn't turn up the culprit, than it must be a third party dependency.  You'll need to go through any includes in your css. Check in your layout file.  You should have something like

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
```

So then open the file `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss`
You will then need to comment out any includes and add them back one by one until you find which library is causing precompilation to fail.  You will need to do this for every layout and/or stylesheet until you find which one is causing the problem.

At the top of each stylesheet you should have a list of includes like

```
  @import 'bootstrap';
```

Or they may look more like this:

```
//*= require jquery-ui
```

So to comment them to not load you can just make them like this while you are testing.

```
// @import 'bootstrap';

// require jquery-ui
```

You may got other compilation errors if you have a lot of 3rd party stuff all over the place, but you have to find the bug somewhere.

Comment: Thank you i think it may be the I need to require Jquery that was very helpful!